# Accessing method variable from button press event while loading data Tkinter Python

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, methods

Following is the part of my python project. I want to be able to access variable x1, and y1 after pressing the button. As shown in last line, i want to obtain values of x1 and y1 at that place. Sorry, i am beginner.

```py
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=2, column=1)


class LoadData:
    def __init__(self, frame1):
        self.frame1 = frame1
        

    def load_data(self):
        
        frame1.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                        initialdir="F:\pycharmprojects\misceleneous\pythonProject",
                        filetypes=(("Text file", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*"))
                        )

        if frame1.filename == "":
            None
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(frame1.filename, usecols=['col1', 'col2'], sep="\t")

            x1 = df['col1']
            y1 = df['col2']
                        
            fig1 = Figure(figsize=(7, 2), dpi=100)
            ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
            ax1.plot(x1, y1)
            
            canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=frame1)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
            canvas1.draw()
            canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1, frame1)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
            
        def on_key_press(event):
            print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
            key_press_handler(event, canvas1, toolbar)

        def _quit():
            frame1.quit()  # stops mainloop
            frame1.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
            # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

        button = tk.Button(master=frame1, text="Quit", command=_quit)
        button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

loaddatax = LoadData(frame1)
button_week = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text="Load Data",
    command=loaddatax.load_data,
    style="TimeButton.TButton"
    )
button_week.grid(row=2, column=0)
x1 = loaddatax.load_data.x1 #--> not working
```

Global variable approach is also not working
I need help regarding

1. x1 is not accessible after pressing button.
2. Is there way by which command will receive data (say x1, y1) which can be used